# Do universities in US contain rooms for discussions between students?

Tags: united-states, university

In India, many universities I know personally do not have any discussion rooms intended for students. There are classrooms (for normal lectures), faculty cabins, seminar halls, administrative buildings, library and labs. None of them allows discussions between two students.

I want to know whether there is a concept of discussion rooms for students in the US.

Answer (score 11):

There is, but it will vary by the university and the department. Some anecdotal examples that I've experienced:

- University #1: When I was an undergraduate (some time ago), our new building had explicit meeting spaces at the end of each floor. (But not rooms; just a semi-encoded area with furniture.)
- University #2: When the library of my previous university was rebuilt about 6 years ago they put in many custom meeting spaces for students to work. These rooms have monitors built into the walls to facilitate meetings and discussions, and the rooms could be booked by students and/or faculty.
- University #2: When the building that I worked in at my previous university was built, about 4 years ago, they also put in several custom meeting rooms for students on each floor. The rooms were similar equipped with monitors.
- University #3: My current university added a building to our department about 15 years ago that has desks in an open area with several cubical-like meeting rooms that can be booked by students. (These are very rarely used by faculty.)

I've visited other universities that have similar spaces. From the discussions that I heard around these buildings, creating space for students to meet seems to be a common value in current construction. But, I haven't typically seen such space available in older buildings or buildings that are highly space constrained.

Comment: My experience at over a dozen U.S. universities (both as a student and faculty member) is that the majority of such discussions take place in libraries, dorm rooms, dorm lounges, [student union buildings](https://www.bestcollegereviews.org/features/most-amazing-campus-student-unions/), and so-called "student commons" areas. Also, some departments have specific tutoring and study areas (see the linked examples in my comment [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/when-should-students-stop-receiving-tutoring-for-mathematics/15455#comment40078_15455)).

Comment: It's nearly always in the library.

Comment: My experience is similar.  There are plenty of places for small groups of students to gather informally.  "Rooms," *i.e.* fully enclosed spaces that would allow for private conversation, are in the libraries.